# How to find the Vagrant IP?

Tags: capistrano, vagrant

I have been developing an automated deployment using Capistrano and using Vagrant as my test virtual server.

The thing is, I need the IP of Vagrant to "`ssh` into it".

I tried `ifconfig` and got the IP but it looks like it is not the exact vagrant IP.

Can anybody help me to get the Vagrant IP?

Comment: Just a reminder to anyone reading this... the way to ssh into a vagrant box is to be located in the folder where Vagrantfile is present, and just type `vagrant ssh`. No IP address is needed. However, for purposes of scripting, or creating a /etc/hosts entry, the answers here are useful, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41251906/1028855) in particular.

Comment: Would also be interesting to get an answer in case of a windows box

Comment: what were you trying to achieve back then? Would you like to answer this question.

Comment: you can also use "vagrant global-status" to get the ID of the running Vagrant box and then do: "vagrant ssh <ID>"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

run:

```
vagrant ssh-config > .ssh.config
```

and then in `config/deploy.rb`

```ruby
role :web, "default"     
role :app, "default"
set :use_sudo, true
set :user, 'root'
set :run_method, :sudo

# Must be set for the password prompt from git to work
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
ssh_options[:config] = '.ssh.config'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `vagrant ssh-config` doesn't show the VM's true SSH config. Using that IP/port will just get you the error "Name or service not known"

Comment: Why was this answer accepted when it is obviously wrong? All this command does is show you the config used on your host to ssh into the vagrant box. If you are using the `private_network` setting in your Vagrantfile and you want to find your VM's IP so you can make HTTP requests to it or whatever, then as noted below, it would appear the only way at the moment is to SSH into it and use `ifconfig` or something to find out.

Comment: I have not used vagrant in a while, but back in the day when I was using it - it was working :)

Comment: This works for me in Vagrant 2.2.3. Run `vagrant ssh-config box_name`. Then `ssh vagrant@<HostName> -p <Port> -i <IdentityFile>` (replacing things in <> with the values returned from Vagrant.

Answer (score 59):

By default, a vagrant box doesn't have any ip address. In order to find the IP address, you simply assign the IP address in your `Vagrantfile` then call `vagrant reload`

If you just need to access a vagrant machine from only the host machine, setting up a "private network" is all you need. Either uncomment the appropriate line in a default `Vagrantfile`, or add this snippet. If you want your VM to appear at `172.30.1.5` it would be the following:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.30.1.5"
```

Learn more about private networks. https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html

If you need vagrant to be accessible outside your host machine, for instance for developing against a mobile device such as iOS or Android, you have to enable a public network you can use either static IP, such as `192.168.1.10`,  or DHCP.

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.10"
```

Learn more about configuring a public network https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html

Comment: This should be the answer. He should Fix Ip addresses from a pool of Static Ips. or create a network design first.

Answer (score 42):

I find that I **do** need the IP in order to configure `/etc/hosts` on the host system to point at services on the fresh VM.

Here's a rough version of what I use to fetch the IP. Let Vagrant do its SSH magic and ask the VM for its address; tweak for your needs.

```
new_ip=$(vagrant ssh -c "ip address show eth0 | grep 'inet ' | sed -e 's/^.*inet //' -e 's/\/.*$//'")
```

---

I just found this in the [Vagrant Docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html). Looks like they consider it a valid approach:

> This will automatically assign an IP address from the reserved address
>   space. The IP address can be determined by using vagrant ssh to SSH
>   into the machine and using the appropriate command line tool to find
>   the IP, such as ifconfig.

Comment: This command resulted in newline characters being included which didn't work when the variable was used in another command like curl (I'm using OSX).  This seemed to work better: `$(vagrant ssh -c "ip address show eth0" 2>/dev/null | sed -ne '/inet / s/\s\+inet \([^\/]\+\).*\r/\1/p')`

Comment: Interesting, I was on OSX when I posted this, though I haven't used vagrant in a while, maybe something changed? Thanks for sharing!

Comment: The better way to remove that newline is to simply add `| tr -d '\n'` like so: `vagrant ssh -c "ip address show eth0 | grep 'inet ' | sed -e 's/^.*inet //' -e 's/\/.*$//' | tr -d '\n'" 2>/dev/null`

Comment: You can also use the '-o' switch. From the `man` page for `ip` (on Fedora, where you have to use it as `/sbin/ip` unless you change your `PATH`): `output each record on a single line, replacing line feeds with the '/' character. This is convenient when you want to count records with *wc*(1) or to *grep*(1) the output.`

Comment: By the way, the command doesn't work for me, giving "Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.", and whenever I use any IP addresses from the `ip` output, I can't connect to them. I can use `vagrant ssh`, but I want to connect to a server inside the VM from the host or another guest.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your VM configuration.  Basically all this command does is list the IP addresses in an attempt to find the public address. You can do this yourself and try to ssh in. If that doesn't work, I'm sure there are plenty of other resources on the net to help. Essentially though, if you're not connecting to the fresh VM via the vagrant user and you don't want to use a password, you'll certainly need to configure an SSH key for the intended user. As far as the "Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.", you can dissect this command and figure out where it is failing.

Comment: I was planning on doing that. I wasn't expecting there to be an easy/fast solution, at least not fast/easy enough for a StackOverflow comment. I more put that in there to warn that I tried this, at a lower level, and it didn't work, so don't take what I said at face value, because it may not work anymore, or may never have worked.

Comment: I figured it out. The IP the VM was giving wasn't the correct one, and the IP I gave the VM was not the one it ultimately used, but I found it in the relevant host-only interface settings of VirtualBox. Therefore, it looks like this answer does not work all the time, but probably works in many situations.

Comment: For such a simple use case of needing an IP, you've got to be kidding me

Comment: Use `vagrant ssh -c "..." -- -q` to put ssh in quiet mode and to get only IP address without any extra messages.

Comment: Also it seems that space characters are added somewhere. To trim them use `IP=$(echo $IP | tr -d '[:space:]')`.

Answer (score 32):

Open a terminal, cd to the path of your Vagrantfile and write this

(Linux)

```
vagrant ssh -c "hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f2" 2>/dev/null
```

(OS X)

```
vagrant ssh -c "hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f2" 2>/dev/null | pbcopy
```

The command for Linux also works for windows. I have no way to test, sorry.

source: https://coderwall.com/p/etzdmq/get-vagrant-box-guest-ip-from-host

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is simple, scriptable, and returns the actual IP address in use by the vagrant box.

Answer (score 17):

I've developed a small **vagrant-address** plugin for that. It's simple, cross-platform, cross-provider, and does not require scripting.

https://github.com/mkuzmin/vagrant-address

Answer (score 9):

In the terminal type:

```
ip addr show
```

Comment: I see a ton of output. How can I know what the IP is within all of that output?

Answer (score 5):

I did at VagrantFile:

```
REMOTE_IP = %x{/usr/local/bin/vagrant ssh-config | /bin/grep -i HostName | /usr/bin/cut -d\' \' -f4}
run "ping #{REMOTE_IP}"
```

As you can see, I used the "%x{}" ruby function.

Comment: Seems to be host OS specific? Which Os do you use as a host?

Answer (score 3):

Terminating a connection open with `vagrant ssh` will show the address, so a dummy or empty command can be executed:

```
$ vagrant ssh -c ''
Connection to 192.168.121.155 closed.
```

Comment: That just returns 127.0.0.1 for me.

Answer (score 1):

We are using VirtualBox as a provider and for the virtual box, you can use `VBoxManage` to get the IP address

```
VBoxManage guestproperty get <virtual-box-machine-name> /VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/1/V4/IP
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: If that's not set, try `enumerate` to get all the guest properties: `VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate <virtual-box-machine-name>`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something like this so i added run bash script inside Vagrant box and take output of public IP address file in host folder.

> Add this in Vagrantfile

```rb
...
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "public-ip.sh"
  config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant'
...
```

> create bash script name public-ip.sh in same Vagrantfile folder

```sh
#!/bin/bash 

# change eth1 to your desired network interface, in my vagrantfile i have first NAT and second is bridge dhcp network and i want to know random dhcp IP.

box_ip=$(ip address show eth1 | grep 'inet ' | sed -e 's/^.*inet //' -e 's/\/.*$//')" 

echo "$box_ip" | tee public_ip.txt

echo "add box ip to your host machine /etc/hosts entry so you can connect the box using box hostname"
```

When you do vagrant up then you will see the vagrant output of the box for public ip or private ip and you can use to add it at host entry whenever box

Answer (score 0):

I needed to know this to tell a user what to add to their host machine's host file.
This works for me inside vagrant using just bash:

```
external_ip=$(cat /vagrant/config.yml | grep vagrant_ip | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs)
echo -e "# Add this line to your host file:\n${external_ip}     host.vagrant.vm"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I haven't seen it here yet... When you `vagrant ssh` into the box, I realized it actually tells you the ip addresses of the interfaces. You can get it there. For example.

```
 {~/Documents/jupyterhub-ansible} (features *%)$  vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-50-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Wed May 22 12:00:34 UTC 2019

  System load:  0.12              Processes:             101
  Usage of /:   56.5% of 9.63GB   Users logged in:       0
  Memory usage: 19%               IP address for enp0s3: 10.0.2.15
  Swap usage:   0%                IP address for enp0s8: 192.168.33.10


10 packages can be updated.
1 update is a security update.


Last login: Wed May 22 12:00:04 2019 from 192.168.33.1
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$
```

In my vagrant file I assigned the address like this:

`config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"`

and as you can see,
`IP address for enp0s8: 192.168.33.10`

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is old but i want to add a few points to this!

you can try

```
vagrant ssh -c "ifconfig | grep inet" hostname
```

this will be easy if you have setup a name to your guests individually!