# /etc/hosts on a Vagrant multi machine setup

Tags: vagrant

I'm working on getting a cluster to do my bidding and to do so they must know about each other. What I'm missing is a way of putting IP/name pairs in /etc/hosts but how do I do that during the provisioning phase?

I can get machine A's IP address when provisioning machine A, but what IP address will be given to machine B?

After a 'vagrant up' I can run a script on the host that finds each machines IP address and updates all their /etc/hosts files but this is a little awkward. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Are you in a position to use static IP addresses for all the nodes in the cluster?

Comment: I probably could, but I'm supposed to build something other admins can try out so the auto IP is quite a nice feature...but static IPs is definitely worth considering.

Comment: You might try SO, there are alot of vagrant gurus building dev environments there.

Answer (score 0):

If the IP addresses of all the machines are fixed then you could write a [provisioning](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/provisioning.html) script that adds the correct entries to `/etc/hosts`. If the addresses are not known until boot then it has to be [determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870900/how-to-find-vagrant-ip) for each of the VMs and fed into the provisioning script. Finally, the the provisioning script to be run for all the VMs.

Comment: That's sort of what I do now, but manually. I hoped for a post provisioning hook that ran a script on the host.